# Display unescaped HTML in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How can I manage to get HTML interpreted inside a mustache binding? At the moment the break (`<br />`) is just displayed/escaped.

Small Vue app:

```
var logapp = new Vue({
  el: '#logapp',
  data: {
    title: 'Logs',
    logs: [
      { status: true, type: 'Import', desc: 'Learn<br />JavaScript', date: '11.11.2015', id: 1  },
      { status: true, type: 'Import', desc: 'Learn<br />JavaScript', date: '11.11.2015', id: 1  }
    ]
  }
})
```

And here is the template:

```
<div id="logapp">    
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-repeat="logs">
                <td>{{fail}}</td>
                <td>{{type}}</td>
                <td>{{description}}</td>
                <td>{{stamp}}</td>
                <td>{{id}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: doing unescaped HTML for line-breaks is overkill, just wanted to mention that!  it's a big security risk

Comment: @RyanTaylor why is it a big security risk?

Comment: @iiirxs if you don't escape the HTML it can load arbitrary javascript etc. you just wanna make sure users can't input stuff there even indirectly.  it's called code injection

Comment: how can this be unsafe since it's provided by the application itself and users have no way to inject malicious code?

Comment: I honestly hear that sort of justification **all** the time. Yes, everyone seems to have a legitimate use case for dynamic code execution, and yes, if you have absolute control of the output and you're thoroughly sanitizing it as a safeguard, sure, knock yourself out - but **unless** it's strictly needed, **why** _would_ you? Why play with fire? The above scenario can **easily** be worked around with `whitespace: pre-wrap` + `\n`. Why take steps to enable and downplay such a classic vulnerability in computer science? It's tiresome to make the case against this every time.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

You can use the `v-html` directive to show it.
like this:

```html
<td v-html="desc"></td>
```

Comment: That one actually works in vue2. First one trows on compile.

Comment: i have a problem with v-html to limit the text, ? is that possible to limit text in v-html ? i tried, it was failed

Comment: Try slicing the variable

Comment: Jut one comment for v-html. Even if this does the job, we need to have in mind that we should render v-html elements which are sanitized otherwise we expose our front end app to xss vulnerabilities. Official doc here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/security.html

Answer (score 235):

Starting with Vue2, the triple braces were deprecated, you are to use `v-html`.

`<div v-html="task.html_content"> </div>`

It is unclear from the [documentation link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) as to what we are supposed to place inside `v-html`, your variables goes inside `v-html`.

Also, `v-html` works only with `<div>` or `<span>` but not with `<template>`.

If you want to see this live in an app, click [here](https://github.com/thewhitetulip/Tasks-vue/commit/d9da739f0ff5968abdac9555e1321dcf30b931c5).

Comment: "but not with `<template>`" is the important part here if you come from Angular.js and look for something like `<ng-include>`

Answer (score 97):

[You can read that here](http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

If you use

```
{{<br />}}
```

it'll be escaped. If you want raw html, you gotta use

```
{{{<br />}}}
```

**EDIT** (Feb 5 2017): As @hitautodestruct points out, **in vue 2 you should use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)** instead of triple curly braces.

Comment: Please note that in vue 2.0 the triple moustache [has been deprecated](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873) you should [use v-html](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-html) instead.

Comment: I do not like in the new method that I often have to create an unnecessary element, purely so that it serves to insert html. This sometimes breaks styles and creates unnecessary nesting.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько really must agree with you on this. Particularly true if you are trying to feed text content as a <slot>... you must create a new element

Answer (score 11):

You have to use v-html directive for displaying html content inside a vue component

```
<div v-html="html content data property"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Vue by default ships with the v-html directive to show it, you bind it onto the element itself rather than using the normal moustache binding for string variables.

So for your specific example you would need:

```
<div id="logapp">    
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-repeat="logs">
                <td v-html="fail"></td>
                <td v-html="type"></td>
                <td v-html="description"></td>
                <td v-html="stamp"></td>
                <td v-html="id"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: works with Vue.js v2.6.8

Answer (score 1):

Before using `v-html`, you have to make sure that the element which you escape is sanitized in case you allow user input, otherwise you expose your app to xss vulnerabilities.

More info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/security.html

I highly encourage you that instead of using `v-html` to use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sanitize)