# Rendering newline character in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a note app where users can add a note by entering multiline text in a textarea. When I save the note in Firebase it is being saved with newline (\n) characters which I want to visualize.

Therefore, I wrote a filter that replaces these characters with `<br />` and that works great.
Though, now I need to render my data using `{{{note.content}}}` and a user can inject HTML, CSS, and JS that will be executed.
Should I use something like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to validate the content or is there a way to safely render newline characters?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

#### Wrap the content in a `pre` element.

A `<pre>` element will **pre**serve whitespace within it, eg:

```html
This is followed by a newline,
not that you can tell
<br />
<br />
<pre>You can see the newline after me!
Woohoo!</pre>
```

Will result in:

```
This is followed by a newline, not that you can tell

You can see the newline after me!
Woohoo!
```

This way, you do not need to do any filtering of newlines.

Comment: I just found that myself too, thank you though! I'll accept your answer

Comment: very clever, never encountered that idea before

Comment: You can also use the [`white-space`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) css attribute, which has a bit more options.

Comment: Using `white-space: break-spaces;` worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 268):

As @shelvacu said the **`<pre>` html tag preserves whitespaces**.

**However using it has one serious disadvantage:** the tag itself inherits plenty of unnecessary styling from CSS frameworks that are used in project (e.g. Bootstrap).

**To preserve whitespaces and avoid inheriting any unnecessary styles use:**

```
<span style="white-space: pre;">Some whitespaced content</span>
```

what will act exacly like the `<pre>` tag.

Be aware that `white-space: pre` remains text 'as it is' - if you would like to have additional line break when it's necessary use: `white-space: pre-wrap`.

See: [w3schools.com CSS white-space Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: I wasn't using any css frameworks so I didn't run into that issue. Nonetheless, that's really helpful, thank you!

Comment: This to me, is the better answer, as wrapping in <pre> tags tends to alter the font with most css frameworks.

Answer (score 70):

Use `white-space: pre-line;` CSS property.

As write in [Mozzila Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) for `pre-line` value:

> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline
>   characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Answer (score 47):

After actually describing my problem I got the idea the use the pre-tag which is for preformatted text. This tag will respect '\t\n' characters and render the text correctly out of the box! 
Though the sentences don't get broken automatically and overflow the width.
With some CSS I was able to get the same behaviour that other elements have.

html:

```
{{note.content}}
```

css:

```
.note pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 37):

Hope this would add value to new visitors.

#### Input from User.

```
I am big line with lots and lots of text which would make me not fit.

Line two ✌ 
Line three
```

[image: Input from user]

#### Best Approach for output

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">Your Content</span>
```

[image: Best Approach Output]

#### Problems with other approach

```
<span style="white-space: pre">Your Content</span>
```

Will result in addition of a scroll on y-axis
[image: with pre style]

Reference & More details: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Question was about rendering "multiline text" not about showing whitespace characters or block code.

Answer (score 16):

i'm not really a fan of `pre` (except in debugging!) so here is another way to deal with this using `v-for`.  this makes it easier to tweak formatting (eg, maybe you want to use a list or something else that is not `span` and `br`)

```js
<span
   v-for="(line,lineNumber) of stringWithNewlines.split('\n')" 
   v-bind:key="lineNumber" >
  {{ line }}<br/>
</span>
```

Comment: Neat solution! You forgot the closing / on the final tag though :)

Comment: really clever and resolves the random formatting issues I was having with pre and lists.

Comment: NICE! was looking for something like that

Comment: but its warning from prettier [vue/no-parsing-error]
Parsing error: x-invalid-end-tag.eslint-plugin-vue
Invalid end tag ["ERROR" - 6:23:47 AM] Void elements do not have end tags "br" (319:31)

Comment: yogi, if you care about the warning a lot, use <br></br> - but that just feels deeply wrong!

Answer (score 5):

I'm able to make it work with backticks (`)

```
<pre>{{textRenderedAsItIs}}</pre>
```

```
data():{
  return{
    textRenderedAsItIs:`Hello
                        World`
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you can do is split up the string and then replace all `\n` with `<br />`  tag.

```
replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
```

you can use `Computed` Properties and then use value `v-html` in DOM:

```
computed: {
    content () {
        return this.note.content.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
    },
}
```

then:

```
<span v-html="content"></span>
```

Before using `v-html`, you have to make sure that the element which you escape is sanitized in case you allow user input, otherwise you expose your app to xss vulnerabilities.

More info [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/security.html)
[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65700291/15760872)

The other way or better way to prevent xss attack that you can do is using the `white-space` CSS property and set it to either `pre-wrap` or `pre-line`.

```
.css-fix {
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* or pre-line */
}
```

These two make sure that the text wraps when line breaks are in the content, and `pre-line` specifically collapses multiple whitespaces into one.

Comment: Using v-html without escaping leads to xss attacks.

Comment: @bradlis7 You are right, I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convert \n to

```
if (this.content.my_val && this.content.my_val !== '') {
    return this.content.my_val.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
}
```

Comment: Using v-html without escaping leads to xss attacks.

Answer (score -2):

you can use v-html

```
<span v-html="yourContent"></span>
```

```
data():{
  return{
    yourContent: "Line 1 <br> Line 2"
   }
}
```

Comment: That is not safe, the user might enter unsafe html which he doesn't control

Comment: It is not safe, before use in html check to prevent xss atack.