# How to force break lines in VuePress markdown files, using default theme?

Tags: vuepress

How to force break lines in VuePress markdown files, using default theme? I have tagline like this:
`tagline: 'Lorem ipsum'`
and I don't know how to split it 2 lines.

I've tried solution mentioned in [VuePress tutorial](https://vuepressbook.com/tutorial/tutorial4.html#markdown-two-adjacent-lines-of-text), that is

```
tagline: 'Lorem⋅⋅
ipsum'
```

(dots represent spaces) but it was still rendered in single line. I am using VuePress v1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The ["frontmatter"](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#frontmatter) of a page is in YAML format and not in Markdown.

Since you can add custom CSS to your Vuepress site, you can use the CSS [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495115/3486675) property to preserve the whitespace from your frontmatter. (Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495115/3486675)).

To target the element that contains the `tagline` specifically, you can add this CSS to a file at `docs/.vuepress/styles/index.styl`:

```
.home .hero .description {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

You can of course modify the CSS to cater for all of the frontmatter properties with maybe just `.home .hero` or even just `.home`.

Then you would be able to use blank lines like you have above in your YAML.

Comment: It didn't work at first, because VuePress didn't keep original whitespaces as they're defined in markdown file when generating output html file, BUT I did some more experiments, and this version finally worked - with the CSS you've provided: `tagline: "Lorem\nipsum"`. Thanks!

Comment: PS I needed to use `white-space: pre-wrap` to keep both line breaks where I needed it, and automatic wrapping of long text in other places.