# Display text as entered in the form with new lines in VueJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a profile filed in the user form as below. The issue I am facing here is when I enter text in this field like as below.

[image: Text entered in form]

[image: How text appear on front end]

In the database, the text is saved with new line characters as shown below:

```
My Name is James Scott. I am a Software Developer.\nI live in New York.\nMy favourite programming language is Ruby and Python.
```

The issue is the text appears as a single line text. There is no new line for I live in New York. And My favourite programming language is Ruby and Python.

Please suggest me how I can resolve this issue. I am using VueJS on frontend and ruby on backend.

```
<v-form :model='user'>
 <v-text-field id="profile"
  ref="profile"
  label="Detailed Profile"
  name="user[profile]"
  v-model='user.profile'
  multi-line
  required
  class="input-element">
 </v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

user.vue

```
<div id="user-profile">{{user.profile}}</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering newline character in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729634/rendering-newline-character-in-vuejs)

Comment: See my comment about `v-html`. It is not safe to use it.

Comment: @DelenaMalan I tried using <div id="user-profile"><pre>{{user.profile}}</pre></div>. But it changes the entire layout. Like it changes the font of the text. 
Can you suggest me what could be the reason behind that?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the content of the `profile`  inside `computed` replacing the `\n` with `<br>`

```
computed:{
  profile:function(){
    return this.user.profile.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
  }
}
```

and in template you can use it as `html` content like this

```
<div id="user-profile" v-html="profile"></div>
```

Comment: Using `v-html` causes the input **not** be to sanitized anymore and makes your app **vulnerable** to XSS. Rather use the [pre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729634/rendering-newline-character-in-vuejs/41495115#41495115) element like in the answers to [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729634/rendering-newline-character-in-vuejs/41495115#41495115) question.