# How to get vue to display line breaks

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to display my product description, but when I render it, the text goes next to each other instead of underneath.
So for example I'm getting

```
description 1 description 2
```

and what I'm trying to get is

```
description 1
description 2
```

When I save my description I save it like this

```
$description = "$description1. \r\n .$description2"
$product->description = $description;
$product->save();
```

and this is how I'm trying to render it in vue

```
<p v-html="product.description"></p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729634/rendering-newline-character-in-vuejs possible duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering newline character in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729634/rendering-newline-character-in-vuejs)

Comment: I think this question is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/36729634/15760872  and I think my answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/76883110/15760872

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the "
" tag similar to this:

```
$description = "$description1. <br> .$description2"
```

Haven't tested so syntax may be slightly different.