# Replace string text with HTML Tag <br>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, replace

this is what I have:

`"de-de": "This is a description for Process\r\nHere is no line break"`

I want to replace the \r\n with an `<br>` tag

This is what I am trying:

```
<p
     v-if="process.description"
     class="description"
     v-html="process.description.replace('\r\n', '<br >')"
>
</p>
```

This works, but if I use `v-html` , there are security warnings in case of XSS vulnerabilities. So v-html isn't the solution ether.

Someone an idea?

Comment: Is process.description user input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering newline character in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729634/rendering-newline-character-in-vuejs)

Comment: This is a string fetched from an api. The string is the result.

Comment: Regardless, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495115/7589775) would be perfect for you.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, You are getting `description` text straight from an API that means it's not directly coming from a user input. In that case you are good to go with `v-html`.

But if you still concern about the XSS vulnerability by using `v-html`, then you can do this with the help of `v-for` and splitting a string.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    description: 'This is a description for Process\r\nHere is no line break'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-for="(line, index) of description.split('\r\n')" :key="index">
    {{ line }}<br/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Up vote. Our solutions are essentially the same, but you posted a few minutes earlier. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Use Vue's built-in security**

It's an interesting problem, but there is a simple solution that leverages Vue's built-in [security](https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/security.html#potential-dangers).

If we split the description at carriage returns we can then use `v-for` with a [template](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-on-template) to output each text fragment appended with a `<br>` break.

```
  <p class="description" v-if="process.description">
    <template v-for="line in process.description?.split('\r\n')">
      {{line}}<br>
    </template>
  </p>
```

Which produces rendered output:

```
<p class="description">
    This is a description for Process<br>
    Here is no line break<br>
</p>
```

**Further Reading**

1. [OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html)
2. [Vue Security Best Practices](https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/security.html)

**Snippet**

For this test, a XSS alert has been embedded in the description. Vue escapes the alert and displays it as text. Yet, if we were to use v-html to render the description it would trigger the XSS alert.

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      process: {
        description: 'This is a description for Process\r\nHere is no line break\r\n<svg/onload=alert("XSS")>'
      }
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.description {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <p class="description" v-if="process.description">
    <template v-for="line in process.description?.split('\r\n')">
      {{line}}<br>
    </template>
  </p>
  
  <!-- v-html will trigger a XSS alert 
  <div v-html="process.description"></div>
  -->
  
  <!-- v-text will NOT trigger XSS alert, but no line breaks 
  <div v-text="process.description"></div>
  -->
  
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your string in a `<pre>` tag instead https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp .

`<pre>` respects line breaks etc and will avoid you doing replacement hacks.