# Vue is automatically escaping html characters

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, filtering, html-escape-characters

here's one of my computed methods:

```
            filtered() {
                return this.groups.map(group => {
                    return group.replace(this.search, '<span class="has-background-primary">' + this.search + '</span>');
                })
            }
```

This is supposed to highlight text in a searchbox, but the `<` is escaped to `&lt;`. What should i do to suppress escaping or how can I do it better?

Comment: wha r u trying to do because as it looks from here you can do this with v-if

Comment: I'm trying to highlight searched text. if I have 'mozambik' in the list and 'zam' in searchbox i want to have moZAMbik, where caps letter are highlighted so it should look like: Mo<span class="has-background-primary">zam</span>bik

Comment: Might be similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877491/vue-display-unescaped-html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track. The only thing missing is a `v-html` at the place where you render your result/list.

```
<div v-for="item in items" v-html="item">
  <!-- if the item now contains raw html it will not be escaped -->
</div>
```

I've created a small fiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/6bto2nkv/

Comment: that was it, I tried with triple braces, but I guess that was old syntax

Comment: Yes, in vue 2.0 the triple moustache has been deprecated