# How to escape HTML string on Moment.js formatter inside Vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

Let's say I have a current date filtered to `February 22nd 2019`. I want the `nd` sign to be inside the `<sup class="small"></sup>` tag. The problem is, I'm using Vue and Moment.js at the same time.

In PHP, I could just do:

`{!! Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('F d<\s\up \c\l\a\s\s\="\s\m\a\l\l\"\>S</\s\up> Y') !!}`

but how can I do that in Javascript and Vue? Or maybe there is cleaner way to do so? Please take a look at my script..

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Textbox -->
        <div class="textbox text-white">
            <p>Realtime Flight Schedule</p>
            <div class="live-datetime">
                <h1>{{ currentDate | filterCurrentDate  }}</h1>
                <digi-clock></digi-clock>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Flight table -->
        <flight-table></flight-table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
    filters: {
        filterCurrentDate(date) {
            return moment(date).format("MMMMM Do Y")
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            currentDate: new Date(),
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Vue display unescaped html*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877491/vue-display-unescaped-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to use [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) for that. So you'd have `filterCurrentDate` generate the HTML from the Moment text, and then use `v-html` to render that as-is.

```
<h1 v-html="filterCurrentDateHTML(currentDate)"></h1>
```

Note I changed the name of the filter to make it explicit that it returns HTML.

For `filterCurrentDateHTML`, perhaps:

```
const m = moment(date);
const ord = m.format("Do");
return `${m.format("MMMMM")} ${ord.replace(/\D/g, '')}<sup class="small">${ord.replace(/\d/g, '')}</sup> ${m.format('Y')}`
```

Comment: it gave me `unexpected token: ${ord.replace(/\d/+, '')}` after `+` sign, sir

Comment: @DonnyPratama - Heh, as it would, that `+` is incorrect. :-) There was another error on that line as well. I've updated the answer, hopefully those are the only two errors there.

Comment: Thank you sir, it works, and I just want to inform you that there is an extra `)` which produce error too after `${m.format('Y')}`

Comment: @DonnyPratama - Sorry about that. Eyes are getting tired. Of course, it's a return statement, not a function call. :-)

Comment: @DonnyPratama - Since you have a handy test case: Does `v-html` work directly on `h1`, or do you need the `span`?

Comment: well, I cannot use filter anymore on `v-html`, so I moved it to a `methods` property and use it like this `<h1 v-html="filterCurrentDateHTML(currentDate)"></h1>`. Yes it works without `span`

Comment: Rather than using `.replace(...)`, you could use `.slice(0,-2)` and `.slice(-2)` respectively, as the suffix is always 2 chars.

Comment: @Styx - Yeah, I thought about that, then decided to allow for locales that had varying-length ordinals. (But not allowing for locales that where the digits vs. non-digits thing wouldn't work, so...possibly inconsistent. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, you're right, I didn't take that into consideration :)