# show raw html in vuetify v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My question seems to be easy, but couldn't figure this out.

I have this

```
  <VSelect :items="common.users.options" ></VSelect> which just shows me select and its options.
```

common.users.options is something like this:

```
[
    { value:".25",text:"&#188; hour" },
    { value:".5",text:"&#189; hour" },
]
```

The bad thing is that VSelect shows me &#188 and &#189 as you see, without transforming it into fraction html.  https://www.codetable.net/decimal/188

how do I show fraction into vselect option's without just plain &#188 ?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877491/vue-display-unescaped-html

Comment: I know I can use {{{ }}} , but i don't know how to do that with Vuetify VSelect.

Comment: I think you are using the Decimal Code instead of Html Entity `&frac14;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Override the `item` and `selection` slots, and use `v-html`.

```html
<v-select :items='item'>
 <template v-slot:item='{item}'> <div v-html='item.text'/> </template>
 <template v-slot:selection='{item}'> <div v-html='item.text'/> </template>
</v-select>
```

Of course you can use something fancier than a `div`.

If you want more succinct code, you can also put a `div` directly in a slot using `slot` and `slot-scope` instead of `v-slot`.

```html
 <div slot='item' slot-scope='{item}' v-html='item.text'/>
```

Newer Syntax

```html
<template #item='{item}'>
  <div v-html='item.text' />
</template>
```

Comment: v-slot can't be used on element other than template and component. I changed div to template. now it's saying can't read the length of undefined.

Comment: I updated solution.  Needed to dereference your object's `item.text`.