# How to print HTML,CSS code in vue js without rendering them as HTML elements and CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Actually I want to built HTML, CSS code ***compiler app*** in ***VueJS*** so that I could show **HTML code and its CSS** separately and then show it's output after **compiling** both.

Comment: i think thats what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877491/display-unescaped-html-in-vue-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display unescaped HTML in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877491/display-unescaped-html-in-vue-js)